# How to get children in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the next models in my app:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    card_number = models.IntegerField()

class Question(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    question_number = models.IntegerField()
    question = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer_number = models.IntegerField()
    answer = models.TextField()
```

So, the question is how to get all answers for all questions for specific card.
It is not a problem to get the child object only for one parent by using _set, but I can't find a way to get all child for the several parent objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
answered = Answer.objects.filter(question__card=specific_card)
```

Comment: @PaulDraper, OP said "get all answers for **all questions** for specific **card**".

Comment: @falsetru, I read "I can't find a way to get all child for the several parent objects." Apparently, Questions were "parents" and cards (which I has thought were parents were "grandparents"). I understand now.